# Determining variables referencing the same value in VS 2013 debugger

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2013, pass-by-reference, watch

While stepping through in Visual Studio 2013 debugger, is there a way to find out, for a currently watched variable, which other variable/field is it currently referencing?

In a classic example below, is it possible to determine at the last line, that f2.bar is actually referencing f1.bar? Alternatively, would there be a quick way to list all by reference variable currently pointing to this value?

```
public class Foo
{
    public string bar;
}

    var f1 = new Foo();
    var f2 = f1;
    f2.bar = "mine";
    f1.bar = "this";
    Console.WriteLine(f2.bar);
    f1.bar = "mine";
    f2.bar = "this";
    Console.WriteLine(f1.bar);
```

outcome:

```
> this
> this
```

Comment: I guess you mean whether `f2` is still pointing to `f1` not `f2.bar` points to `f1.bar`. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, You can use the [Make Object ID](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimgries/archive/2005/11/16/493431.aspx) feature.

All you have to do is give the object Id for `f1` earlier at some point in debugging. Later you can inspect the `f2`-- if `f2` points to the same `f1` debugger will show you the object id which was created with `f1`, otherwise no.

In other words "Make Object ID" will tell you whether you're looking at the same reference or not.

Comment: I knew about object id, thank you, but the whole trick is to be able to back track to the origins of the variable at the current breakpoint.

Comment: What do you mean by back track the origin of the currently observed variable?

Comment: @Damian I think what you are looking for is not possible in VS ("what else refers to given object") and "Make Object Id" is likely the best you can do (i.e. in your case both "f1" and "f2" will have object with the same id). If you have issue that can't be found this way (or via code reviews/test) - you can always go WinDbg route with `!gcroot`- i.e. [Tracking down managed memory leaks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2004/12/10/279612.aspx) shows all steps...